# Getting an InvalidCastException within DbUpdateException when updating SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception

We have a DB admin web application that creates, updates, and deletes entries in our SQL Server database. Built with ASP.NET MVC and using Entity Framework 2.2, the application successfully works when creating and updating almost all tables within the database. However, I am experiencing a Db Update Exception when updating a specific table. The inner exception is an

> Invalid Cast Exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'

A model of this table was created with EF Core Power Tools to include all of the columns in this table. I am able to create new entries in the table without a problem, but when I use the application to update ANY value I get the exception. There is a view for creating and view for editing. There are around 50 columns to this problem table with a concatenated primary that includes 2 columns, and 1 non-nullable column. All other columns allow NULLS.

I can CREATE a record with little or all values filled without an issue. I can edit an entry without making a change. But whenever I make a change to any field, I get the error.

I have tried eliminating fields to try to narrow down if it's a specific one, but that was fruitless. I have triple-checked that the data types of the properties in the model class line up with the data types of the table. Everything is correct... besides, if it was not then I would be getting the same error when creating.

Here is my truncated model class:

```
public partial class SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC
{
    [DataTablesAttributeRowId]
    public string RowId { get { return String.Format("{0}_{1}", SELLING_STYLE_NBR, CUST_REFERENCE_NBR); } }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string SELLING_STYLE_NBR { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string selling_company { get; set; }
    public string density { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string construction_type { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string electrstatic_propensity { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string protective_treatments { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string smoke_density { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public int? introduction_date { get; set; }
    public string stitches_per_inch { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string CUST_REFERENCE_NBR { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string greige_good_nbr { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string inventory_style_nbr { get; set; }
    public bool? is18x36 { get; set; }
    public bool? isHex { get; set; }
    public bool? enableViz { get; set; }
    public bool? enableCustomViz { get; set; }
    public bool? enableGenericViz { get; set; }
    public bool? is9x36Tile { get; set; }
    public bool? isFacetTile { get; set; }
    public int? product_subtype_id { get; set; }
    ...
```

Here is my `Create` method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("SELLING_STYLE_NBR,selling_company,...")] SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        _context.Add(sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC);
}
```

Here is my `Edit` method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("SELLING_STYLE_NBR,selling_company,...")] SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            if (!SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPECExists(sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC.SELLING_STYLE_NBR))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            var exception = HandleDbException(ex);
            return View("Error", new System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo(exception,"SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC","Edit"));
        }

        // redirect back to List page if referrer is available (only for models with FK)
        var referrer = Request.Form["Referrer"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(referrer))
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        else
            return Redirect(referrer);
    }

    return View(sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC);
}
```

Here is the Stack:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync(Int32
>   commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader
>   reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   CPSDataAdmin.Controllers.SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPECController.Edit(String
>   id, SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC sC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPEC) in
>   C:\Projects\cps-data-admin\CPSDataAdmin\Controllers\SC_CUSTOM_STYLE_SPECController.cs:line 379
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Comment: In which line the exception has thrown? If you can provide stack trace, it may explain what things went wrong while executing `SaveChangesAsync()`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it breaks at `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` after the `Update` command in the `Edit` method. I have added the stack trace above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for triggers on the table! I found this question while facing the same problem and mine turned out to be a trigger that performed a select.

EF was running a statement along the lines of

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [ProblemTable] SET [IrrelevantColumn] = @p0
WHERE [id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

and expected ONLY the @@rowcount result set to come back. The trigger was selecting a varchar column from the affected row, which left EF trying to parse a rowcount from "ABC1234DEF". I don't know why the trigger was doing that select, but I assume it comes down to one of my predecessors debugging in prod.

Answer (score 0):

What is this this `[DataTablesAttributeRowId]` attribute?  Does your table have a column called "RowId"? You mention a concatenated (composite?) key. Normally if this is a PK made up of 2x columns, you would declare a Key mapping:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
[Required] 
[StringLength(5)]
public string SELLING_STYLE_NBR { get; set; }
// ...
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
[Required]
[StringLength(3)]
public string CUST_REFERENCE_NBR { get; set; }
```

In the database are these both Varchar/NVarchar columns? It seems unusual to be using text PK/FKs in a system where the naming implies they are numeric.

Entity declarations should reflect the table schema and relationships between tables. To assist with assessing mapping issues, please include the relevant table structure. There are a few smells with your code sample including that attribute, and the different naming conventions.

Comment: This application was not originally built by my team, so the way they added the `RowId` is a bit of a mystery, but it seems to work for other tables that have that format. It also has no problem with it when creating, as I noted above. So why would it have a problem with it when updating this table, but not another table that has the same? For example, we have a color spec table that has a `RowId` that consists of 3 columns, and I have no issue updating entries in that table with this application.